# After updating the UEFI Bios on my Asus Prime B350-PLUS motherboard I can't play MP4 files on any video player

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu, 23.04

However, **if I boot into recovery mode, I can play the videos just fine**. Here are the errors I'm getting from kern.log and syslog:

> vlc_vlc.desktop[3877]: radeon: The kernel rejected CS, see dmesg for
> more information (-2)
>
> kernel: [21688.584828] [drm:radeon_uvd_cs_msg [radeon]] ERROR Invalid
> UVD handle 0xe46a0001!
>
> kernel: [21688.584988] [drm:radeon_cs_ioctl [radeon]] ERROR Invalid
> command stream !

This is my set up:

> OS: Ubuntu 23.04
>
> Motherboard: Asus Prime B350-Plus
>
> Processor: AMD
>
> Ryzen 5 1400 Graphics:Radeon HD 5450

How do I resolve this issue? Do I need to uninstall and then reinstall the open source AMD Radeon driver? Or should I uninstall the open source driver and install the proprietary driver from AMD's site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by reinstalling Ubuntu. It's a bad solution because I did not figure out why the new UEFI BIOS update caused this issue or how to remediate it.